# Javafx task/thread does not start

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, task

I have a JavaFX Program, where I want to import a file and read everything out of this file (should be a .txt) and write it into a String, so I can work on it. Because the files are big sometimes and leave my program saying "No response" and stuff like that, I wanted to add a ProgressBar, to show the current Progress and stop the program from crashing.

At first, I just added a ProgressBar to a Dialog, that opens and updates per binding. But the GUI didn't update, so I found out I have to do a new Thread, that runs in the background, so my program doesn't stop responding. So I packed everything into a Task and started the task with a Thread, but now the Dialog with the ProgressBar doesn't even show up, so I debugged it and found out that the program doesn't even do the task, it just like, goes over it without doing anything.

Here is my current code, I hope anyone can help me with my problem or explain Tasks/Threads to me:

MyHandler:

```
package application.handler;

import application.data.KTChat;
import application.gui.MyRootPane;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MyHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
    private MyRootPane mp;
    private FileChooser fc;
    private Stage primaryStage;
    private KTChat kt;

    public MyHandler(MyRootPane mp, Stage primaryStage) {
        this.mp = mp;
        fc = new FileChooser();
        fc.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Text files (*.txt)", "*.txt"));
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        kt = new KTChat(mp);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            String mdata = ((MenuItem)(event.getSource())).getId();
            if(mdata.equalsIgnoreCase("import")) {
                kr.readFile(fc.showOpenDialog(primaryStage));
            }
    }
    public KTChat getKT() {
        return kt;
    }
}
```

MyRootPane (my GUI):

```
package application.gui;

import java.io.File;

import application.handler.MyHandler;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MyRootPane extends BorderPane {
    private TextArea eingabe = new TextArea();
    private TextArea ausgabe = new TextArea();
    private MenuBar mb = new MenuBar();
    private Menu m2 = new Menu("Settings");
    private MenuItem mi4 = new MenuItem("Import chat");
    private Stage primaryStage;
    private MyHandler mh;
    private FortschrittDialog fd = new FortschrittDialog();

    public MyRootPane(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        mh = new MyHandler(this, primaryStage);
        initSettings();
        setTop(mb);
        setCenter(eingabe);
        setBottom(ausgabe);
    }
    public void initSettings() {
        ausgabe.setEditable(false);
        eingabe.setPrefHeight(500);
        ausgabe.setPrefHeight(500);

        mi4.setId("import");
        mi4.setOnAction(mh);
        m2.getItems().add(mi4);
        mb.getMenus().add(m2);
    }
    public void eingabeSetText(String eingabe) {
        this.eingabe.setText(eingabe);
    }
    public String eingabeGetText() {
        return eingabe.getText();
    }
    public void startFortschrittDialog() {
        fd.show();
    }
    public void endFortschrittDialog() {
        fd.close();
    }
    public void isFortschrittDialogCompleted() {
        if(fd.isCompleted()) endFortschrittDialog();
    }
    public DoubleProperty progressP() {
        return fd.getPBProgressProperty();
    }
}
```

Then my KTChat where the String should have been build originally:

```
package application.data;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import application.gui.MyRootPane;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableDoubleValue;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

public class KTChat {

    private String chat;

    private MyRootPane mp;

    public KTChat(MyRootPane mp) {
        this.mp = mp;
    }
    public void setChat(String eingabeGetText) {
        this.chat = eingabeGetText;
        getChat();
    }
    public void readFile(File chat) {
        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                if(chat.getName().contains("KakaoTalk_")) {
                    mp.startFortschrittDialog();
                    mp.setFortschritt(-1.0f);
                    String s = "";
                    String gesamt = "";
                    double laenge = 0;
                    try(BufferedReader brCount = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(chat))) {
                        while((s=brCount.readLine())!=null) {
                            laenge++;
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Fehler beim zählen");
                    }
                    double momentanErreicht = 0;
                    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(chat))) {
                        while((s=br.readLine())!=null) {
                            momentanErreicht++;
                            updateProgress(momentanErreicht, laenge);
                            s = s.replace("ÃŸ", "ß");
                            s = s.replace("Ã¶", "ö");
                            s = s.replace("Ã¼", "ü");
                            s = s.replace("Ã¤", "ä");
                            s = s.replace("Ã„", "Ä");
                            s = s.replace("Ãœ", "Ü");
                            s = s.replace("Ã–", "Ö");
                            gesamt += s+"\n";
                        }
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                        System.out.println("File not found");
                    } catch (IOException e2) {
                        System.out.println("IOException");
                    }
                    mp.isFortschrittDialogCompleted();
                    mp.eingabeSetText(gesamt);
                    setChat(mp.eingabeGetText());
                    getChat();
                } else mp.mhNichtPassendesFile();
                return null;
            }
        };
        mp.progressP().bind(task.progressProperty());
        Thread th = new Thread(task);
        th.setDaemon(true);
        th.start();
    }
```

The Dialog where my ProgressBar is:

```
package application.gui;

import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class FortschrittDialog extends Dialog {

    private ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();

    public FortschrittDialog() {
        pb.setPrefWidth(500);
        pb.setProgress(-1f);

        getDialogPane().setContent(pb);
    }
    public DoubleProperty getPBProgressProperty() {
        return pb.progressProperty();
    }
    public boolean isCompleted() {
        if(pb.getProgress()==1.0) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

And last but not least the Main class:

```
package application;

import application.gui.MyRootPane;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            MyRootPane root = new MyRootPane(primaryStage);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,1280,720);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setTitle("KT-Chat-Statistics V1.1");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I tried to include everything that is relevant for the problem, you should be able to just Copy Paste the code to test it for yourself. I really don't understand why it is not working.

Comment: There are likely quite a few issues here, one example is that the start method is invoked by the JavaFX system, so I am not sure why you are trying to call start explicitly.  Also, why duplicate code in KTChat and ImportFile?

Comment: To get the best help, it is usually best to supply a [mcve], which somebody could copy and paste, without modification, to execute and replicate the issue.  Such code is generally far smaller than the code pasted in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I wanted to show both methods, one in a class that extends Application and one in a "normal" class, because I read in a other question on this site that tasks have to be in a class, extended by Application, and I'm not sure if this was wrong or right

Comment: It's wrong, a Task is a separate class, it does not need to be created or defined in a class that extends Application.  Showing both methods in your question is confusing as it is difficult for the reader to work out what you are doing when you include redundant code.

Comment: Thank you, I deleted the unnecessary additional code, I hope you can understand better now, what I meant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem. For everyone else who is experiencing the same problem or just wants to know, here is what I did wrong:

You can't call JavaFX-Thread-Methods during your background task, so every method that reaches outside the Task (I think only the mp.-methods) will not be executed.
Therefore, the ProgressBar in the Dialog I made will function, but the Dialog will just not be shown, because the method to show the Dialog lays in the MyRootPane-Class. And as we now know, JavaFX-Thread-Methods can not be executed during the background task.

So, here is what exactly changed in the code, so it can function:
You have to put all mp.-methods outside the task, so before you start the task through the thread, just open the dialog there, like:

```
        mp.progressP().bind(task.progressProperty());
        mp.startFortschrittDialog();
        Thread th = new Thread(task);
        th.setDaemon(true);
        th.start();
```

I hope this is clear and easy to understand, thank you all for your time.